# maxConnections default value for tomcat running on windows 7

Tags: tomcat7

I am new to tomcat and want to know the default value for maxConnection for tomcat on windows 7 .
Have checked http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html which says

> maxConnections  : The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time. When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections based on the acceptCount setting. Default value varies by connector type. For BIO the default is the value of maxThreads unless an Executor is used in which case the default will be the value of maxThreads from the executor. For NIO the default is 10000. For APR/native, the default is 8192.
>   Note that for APR/native on Windows, the configured value will be reduced to the highest multiple of 1024 that is less than or equal to maxConnections. This is done for performance reasons.
>   If set to a value of -1, the maxConnections feature is disabled and connections are not counted.

I am not sure if `<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />` comes under BIO or NIO or APR/native

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I gathered from Tomcat's documentation:

If you don't specify it explicitly through the `protocol` attribute of the `Connector` element (as in your example above), tomcat will search native libraries (through the LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Unixes or Path environment variables on Windows) for APR connector and if the connector is not found it will use BIO (Blocking IO) connector (see description of the protocol attribute [Tomcat HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)).

For a BIO connector, if not specified `maxConnections` will assume the value of `maxThreads` attribute. Default value in turn for `maxThreads` is 200 unless you use the 'executor' attribute pointing to an [Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html) element in which case it will be the value of maxThreads of the executor element.

Comment: Right. In out performance testing our tomcat was able to handle only 300( 200(default maxThreads) + 100(default acceptCount) ). Your explanation makes perfect sense. Thanks.